# How does getBody() work from Gmail in Google App Script?

Tags: html, regex, google-apps-script, dom

Let's say message.getBody() returns this [result](https://regex101.com/r/c4pODV/1) as:

```
<p>Stejně jako došlo ke změně stezek, pracuje se také na aktualizaci odborek.</p>
 <p>Aktuální podobu odborek zde nabízíme ke stažení:</p>
 <table>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td><a href="dokumenty/file/517-odborne-zkousky-pro-skauty-a-skautky">Odborky pro skauty a skautky</a></td>
 <td><a href="dokumenty/file/517-odborne-zkousky-pro-skauty-a-skautky"><img src="http://static.krizovatka.skaut.cz/noRW_photodisplay/7223_9bd54a63a4719dc5fb347735fa81cd27.jpg?1324651878" alt="" height="80" width="80" /></a></td>
 <td>Kompletní odborky. Rok vydání 1998. <a href="dokumenty/file/517-odborne-zkousky-pro-skauty-a-skautky">Stahujte</a>, <a href="http://www.obchod.skaut.cz/publikace/Odborne-zkousky-skautek-a-skautu.html">Kupte si</a></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

We can use this regular express `href=\"(.*?)\"`  to extract the "`dokumenty/file/517-odborne-zkousky-pro-skauty-a-skautky`" from `<td><a href="dokumenty/file/517-odborne-zkousky-pro-skauty-a-skautky"><img src="http://static.krizovatka.skaut.cz/noRW_photodisplay/7223_9bd54a63a4719dc5fb347735fa81cd27.jpg?1324651878" alt="" height="80" width="80" /></a></td>`

***Question: Now how can we do the same when the message.getBody() method return one line "object"/string***  as:

```
<!doctype html><html><div style="width: 100%; max-width: 650px;"><div style="font-family: &#39;Arial&#39;;"><table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-left: 1px solid #e4e4e4; border-right: 1px solid #e4e4e4;"><tr><td style="background-color: #f8f8f8; border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4; border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding-left: 18px;"></td><td style="background-color: #f8f8f8; border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4; border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 18px 10px 9px 0px;" valign=middle><a style="text-decoration: none;" href=//trends.ama.com/trends?utm_source=storyfinder&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=v1&amp;utm_content=logo><img alt="Ama Trend" border=0 height=24 src=https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/lockups/1x/lockup_trends_color_142x24dp.png></a></td><td style="background-color: #f8f8f8; border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4; border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding-right: 18px;"></td></tr><tr><td style="padding-left: 32px;"></td><td style="font-family: &#39;Arial&#39;; line-height: 20px; padding: 29px 0 0 0; vertical-align: middle;"><span style="color: #1f1f1f; font-size: 22px;">   is trending today on Ama.</span><div style="color: #666; font-size: 13px; line-height: 16px; padding-top: 6px; vertical-align: top;"><span>Taiwan</span><span style="padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px">⋅</span><a style="color: #aaa; text-decoration: none;">Saturday, December 18, 2021</a></div></td><td style="padding-right: 32px;"></td></tr><tr><td colspan=3 style="height: 15px;"></td></tr><tr><td style="padding-left: 18px;"></td><td style="border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4 ; font-family: &#39;Arial&#39;; padding: 18px 0 12px 0; vertical-align: top;"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href=https://feed.ama.com/g/p/AD-FnEwizam9DvKiTR8XdAnbGCe0o6Dng65WkxklEQ6P9ueoMRpGG00NLVX_PA5lHPz6DeGQvaURUnCuEI9PzRQNQHR1-t1Elpru3e1nbbJlhlUZ3FbFv2am><table align=right style="display: inline; border-collapse: collapse; padding-bottom: 5px;"><tr><td style="padding-left: 18px;"></td><td style="background-repeat: no-repeat; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 0; text-align: center;" valign=bottom background=https://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2Ig9w7TRcJptTamszZOz9ZusluWcuTdwEcZbeLb31PgquvyjBmrje4WMzBA8f8SUYbFpHBX0k height=100 width=100><!--[if gte mso 9]><v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height: 100px; width: 100px; top:0; left:0; border:0; z-index:1;'</div></td><td style="padding-right: 32px;"></td></tr></table></div></div><img alt="" height=1 width=3 src=https://feed.ama.com/g/img/AD-FnEyO4-BP639s1TuG_VZB2QMQM1OiAziES42-qyAMNpSqbMY.gif></html>
```

Then calls a function as `returns null` in  Google App Script:

```
....
str = message.getBody()
result= myFunction(str)
function myFunction(str){
  var re  = /href=\"(.*?)\"/g;
  var result = "";
  while ((res=re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    result += res[1] + "\n";
  };
  return result.slice(0,-1);
}
```

How can we make this regex work in Google App Script ?

Comment: well in the one line "object"/string the value of `href=`s  are not wrapped in double quotes `""`. so it dont find a match.

Comment: Thank you. any suggestion to make it work without the "".

Comment: `/href=(.*?)(?:>|\s)/g` well only matching `>` should also work in this case but will also match other attributes that follows `href` if there were any. so to avoid that you can match till `>` or a space i.e `\s`.

Comment: @K450 ingesting, the regex you gave only work in https://regex101.com but  not in Google App Script.

Comment: @mmmmmmmmmmmmm It should work.

Comment: `var re = new RegExp("href=(.*?)(?:>|\s)","g");` try this

Comment: Yes. woking now. there is some other issue with my code. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const myFunction = (str, regex) => {
    const result = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), (x) => x[2] ?? x[1]);
    return result.join("\n");
}

const str = message.getBody()
const regex = /\shref=("([^"]*)"|[^\s>]+)/gi;
result = myFunction(str, regex)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ImzxJL/1). *Details*:

- `\s` - a whitespace
- `href=` - a fixed string
- `("([^"]*)"|[^\s>]+)` - Group 1:

  - `"([^"]*)"` - a `"` char, then Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` outside of Group 1
  - `|` - or
  - `[^\s>]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `>`.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const myFunction = (str, regex) => {
    const result = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), (x) => x[2] ?? x[1]);
    return result.join("\n");
}

const text = `<tr>
 <td><a href="dokumenty/file/517-odborne-zkousky-pro-skauty-a-skautky">Odborky pro skauty a skautky</a></td>...<img ...valign=middle><a style="text-decoration: none;" href=//trends.ama.com/trends?utm_source=storyfinder&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=v1&amp;utm_content=logo><img alt="`;
 const regex = /\shref=("([^"]*)"|[^\s>]+)/gi;
console.log(myFunction(text, regex));
```